# How can I quickly look through the images and videos within a folder

Tags: video, filesystem, gthumb, heic

Is there an app that can allow me to preview photos and videos within a single folder? It does not necessarily have to be a "preview" it could simply open an app but I want to be able to scroll through each one quickly using the left or right buttons. I am looking for something similar to mac's preview feature using the space bar (I am not sure if that is still how the feature works I have not used a mac since 2014).

Alternatively, is there an app that can store both photos and videos together similar to the google photos, ios photos gallery, or android gallery layouts?

Either way, the app must be able to view HEIC, HEIF, MP4, MOV, PNG, JPEG etc.

I tried gthumb however it will not open HEIC files. But, I can view HEIC files using the native "image viewer" app. Also, gthumb does not have clear dating like google photos which is the main feature I want to keep If I go with a photo management app.

EDIT 8/1/22:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-preview.html.en is exactly what I am looking for. However, the only issue now is that I cannot use it to view HEIC files. Although, I can view HEIC files with image viewer.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-preview.html.en ?

Comment: @FedKad this solves 99% of my problems please see the edit for an additional question/issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gwenview is very powerful, and has a tiled gallery supporting both images and videos.